# Why is 'sh -c' returning a different result from my actual command?

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to get the number of pages in a PDF file through the command line.

```
pdfinfo "/tmp/temp.pdf" | grep Pages: | awk '{print $2}'
```

produces

```
3
```

In Node.js, I need to use 'sh' because of the piping.

But

```
sh -c "pdfinfo '/tmp/temp.pdf' | grep Pages: | awk '{print $2}'"
```

produces

```
Pages:          3
```

Why am I getting different output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sh -c` command is double quoted, which will expand the `$2` which is likely empty, so the `awk` command becomes just `print` which prints the whole line.  You could escape the `$` to prevent it from being expanded:

```
sh -c "pdfinfo '/tmp/temp.pdf' | grep Pages: | awk '{print \$2}'"
```

Incidentally, `awk` can do pattern matching, so no need for both `grep` and `awk`:

```
pdfinfo "/tmp/temp.pdf" | awk '/Pages:/ {print $2}'
```